# How to call WebMethod service in WindowForm

Tags: c#

How to update server data through a webservice by using ADO.NET and Visual C#.NET

WebMethod

```
     public void UpdateDeMo1(DataSet ds)
     {
         LayerAccess ac = new LayerAccess();
         string[] parameters = { };
         object[] values = { };
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
         da = ac.getDataAdapter("P_Demo", parameters, values);
         SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
         da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
         //return ds;
     }
```

But the error occurs when calling WebMethod.

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ud.AutoUpdateDemo(gridControl1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)gridControl1.DataSource;
        dtt = dt.Copy();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("B");
        ds.Tables.Add(dtt);
        DataSet dschang = new DataSet();
        dschang = ds.Copy();
        sv.UpdateDeMo1(dschang.Copy());
    }
```

[image]

Please help me.